# Lithium PHP Framework - unable to upload files on live site

Tags: php, frameworks, lithium

I'm working on a site, that is live already, and when I attempt to upload a file - I receive "Status Code: 201 Created", but no content after that.
And when I run the site locally and upload the file - I get the same status code, but after that I get content - JSON with the data of the newly created file.

In both cases I see in the Mongo database that the file is created, and when I attempt to access it through a controller for it through

`http://({domain}file/{{file-id}}`

I see the file - even on live.

The problem appears to be somewhere after that saving ... and before [[something]] returns the JSOn with the file data ...

... but because everything in Lithium is soooooooooooooooo muuuuuuucccchhhhhhhh automated ... I don't know how to find the problem.

(And I don't want to dump inside the framework itself ... I'm supposed to use the framework, not to debug it! ...)

Comment: What kind of web server are you using? Apache? Nginx? How does it connect to php? mod_php, php-fpm? I wonder if the issue is with that configuration and not inside Lithium.

Comment: Apache 2.4.7 with PHP 5.5.9 ... that's on the live server. Locally I'm with PHP 5.3.x ... but I'd be very surprised if the problem is caused by the different versions.

Comment: After some debugging I managed to find out, that the problem comes from `json_encode()`, which converts the inserted-in-the-DB file to JSON, before the server sends the response. One of the field in the array that's about to be encoded, is a veeeery long string that locally turns into `null` ... so it apparently is not UTF-8, but on live server breaks the whole functionality. ... (After the json_encode() I call json_last_error() and on both locally and live it gives me `int(5)` ... but on live it breaks the stuff ... :( ...

Comment: Hmm... there may have been changes to json_encode between 5.3 and 5.5. You should upgrade your local version and see if you can reproduce the problem. Are you calling `json_encode()` explicitly or is that coming from Lithium's [json media handler output](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/791c2ce345b63cd47f067cdebccb6497a35de014/net/http/Media.php#L918)? It seems that `json_encode()` emits a warning if invalid utf8 data is encountered. Maybe your production environment picks up that warning and handles the output differently?

Comment: Here's a snippet that reproduces the `json_encode()` error in case that's helpful: `var_dump(json_encode(["blah" => base64_decode("5aW96ZuF77yM5ZKx5p2l5LiA5L+X55qE77yM5pS56Ieq5Lic5Y2X6KW/5YyX6aOO44CCCuS4juS9oOebuOmAou+8jOWFqOaYr+acuue8mOW3p+WQiOOAguWPr+Wtpui1t+adpeWNtOW/g+aGlOaCtOOAggrmgLvmmK/ovpPkuoborqnlho3ljrvlrabvvIzlrabkuobo")]));`

Comment: Well, a property of the object that is about to be iterated, is not UTF8 encoded. That's the problem. (I'm not calling it, it happens in the handler, on line 775.) ... So - my goal now is to clear any non-utf8 chars from the object, returned from the DB insertion, and then I think the json encoding will not produce any problems :) ... How does it sound as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem appeared to be that after the upload the server should return JSON with the data for the file, but on live `json_encode()` was returning `false` because of some non-UTF8 text in the object. I managed to workaround this ... and the solution can be found in this question I posted today: [json_encode() turn non-UTF8 strings into null, but on live site returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673394/json-encode-turn-non-utf8-strings-into-null-but-on-live-site-returns-false)