# json_encode() turn non-UTF8 strings into null, but on live site returns false

Tags: php, utf-8, null, json

In the framework I have to use for a project (Lithium) the output on a specific page goes through `json_encode()`. Locally and on live I try with one and the same data, and the result is:

1. Locally it returns the JSON, but some of the values are turned into `null`.
2. Live site - it returns `false`.

In both cases when I run `json_last_error()` - it gives me `int(5)`. I can run `phpinfo()` on both places, if some setting is causing the problem.
(Locally I'm with PHP 5.3.*, on live it's 5.5.9.)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is: "How to make json_encode() to return JSON even in the cases the-provided-object-for-encoding contains non-UTF8 characters?" Cause currently I'm getting `false` ...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use optional parameters of json_encode in case of UTF8 characters

So You can use

**JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**
 option of 
    [JSON_ENCODE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Example:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: I tried this, but `json_encode()` still returns `false` :( ... and after that I get `int(5)` if I try `json_last_error()`.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [php documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Although this is not documented on the version log here, non-UTF8 handling behaviour has changed in 5.5, in a way that can make debugging difficult.

Passing a non UTF-8 string to json_encode() will make the function return false in PHP 5.5, while it will only nullify this string (and only this one) in previous versions.

In a Latin-1 encoded file, write this:

```
$a = array('é', 1);
var_dump(json_encode($a));
```

PHP < 5.4: `string(8) "[null,1]"`

PHP >= 5.5: `bool(false)`

PHP 5.5 has it right of course (if encoding fails, return false) but its likely to introduce errors when updating to 5.5 because previously you could get the rest of the JSON even when one string was not in UTF8 (if this string wasn't used, you'd never notify it's nulled)

Answer (score 0):

Finally - I used a slightly modified version of this gist - http://gist.github.com/oscar-broman/3653399 - but instead of encoding properties - I'm removing all the non-UTF8 strings ... and it's working. But - I had to modify the PHP framework the website is using ... and this is something I was really trying to avoid ... ... ... ... but anyway, this approach does the job for now :) ...

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with PhP 7.3.

You can fix it in multiple ways :

1. Ignore no-UTF8 char

```php
json_encode(array("a" => "ç"), JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
```

This solution is fine if you just want to ignore all possible strange caractere, without trying to show them.

2. Replace no-UTF8 char

```php
json_encode(array("a" => "ç"), JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

This is possible, but in my case I was getting "?" result.

3. UTF8-ize char

```php
json_encode(array("a" => utf8_encode("ç")));
```

I'm using this solution which just convert into UTF8 format all char.